# Grafana summary dashboards receive data but per-service dashboards do not

Tags: grafana, prometheus, istio

What have I done wrong?

I installed Istio last week on GKE and, when following the instructions step-by-step, everything appeared to work correctly including all the Grafana dashboards.

This week I attempted to recreate the configuration to share with my team. Everything appears to work correctly *except* the per-service (e.g. productpage) dashboards that report "no datapoints".

[image]

I did delete and recreate some resources out of order and perhaps this explains my error?

I would appreciate a heuristic that could help me diagnose where I've gone wrong and how to address. My largest area of non-familiarity is with Prometheus. Clearly Grafana is connected to Prometheus. What could I check in Prometheus to ensure it's configured correctly?

[image]

Perhaps I should simply delete and recreate but, I'd like to learn from this experience.

```
istioctl version:

Version: 0.1.5
GitRevision: 21f4cb4
GitBranch: master
User: jenkins@ubuntu-16-04-build-de3bbfab70500
GolangVersion: go1.8.1
KubeInjectHub: docker.io/istio
KubeInjectTag: 0.1


apiserver version:

Version: 0.1.5
GitRevision: 21f4cb4
GitBranch: master
User: jenkins@ubuntu-16-04-build-de3bbfab70500
GolangVersion: go1.8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

When we've seen this before, it is typically fixed by just refreshing the page in the browser. The metrics powering the summary dashboards are the same ones that are used to power the service graphs.

Can you try refreshing the page and seeing what happens?

Comment: Thanks @douglas-reid. Yes, I'd tried refreshing and redefining the data source but to no avail. I've since deleted the project. A subsequent one worked correctly. I'll try again this week and update here if I learn more.